# ReactJS Route Components/Render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-router-component

I created a simple booking app with  3 files, `App.js`, `Booked.js` (1st child) and `Details.js` (2nd child) 
I'm trying to access `App.js` to delete a data using the 2nd child(`Detail.js`) but I can't proceed because it throws me an error of

> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined"

Whenever I try to add function to a Route Component to access `App.js`

This is the main page
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PrM8.png 
When I click the data which is in Booked.js i get redirected to Details.js to view the specific data https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2EnL.png 
Using this code, a Route with component works

```
<Route path="/details" component={Details} />
```

But after adding a function gives me an error

```
<Route path="/details" component={ () => <Details delBook={this.delBook} /> } />
```

or

```
<Route path="/details" render={()=><Details delBook={this.delBook}/>}/>
```

Link in Booking.js

```
 <Link
  to={{
  pathname: "/details",
  state: {
  id: booking.id,
  fname: booking.fname,
  lname: booking.lname,
  email: booking.email,
  ddate: booking.ddate,
  ttime: booking.ttime
  }
  }}
  key={booking.id} 
  style={linkStyle}>
```

In Details.js where the error throws.

```
 state = {
    id: this.props.location.state.id,
    fname:  this.props.location.state.fname,
    lname:  this.props.location.state.lname,
    email: this.props.location.state.email,
    ddate: this.props.location.state.ddate,
    ttime: this.props.location.state.ttime,
}
```

Can someone help and explain why is this happening ? 
Any solution or alternatives ? 
TIA!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind `this` when passing it as a prop. Also it's a good idea to pass the router's props as well:

```
<Route path="/details" component={ (routerProps) => <Details delBook={this.delBook.bind(this)} {...routerProps} />  } />
```

Also in `Details.js` you should use `props` directly, instead from `this`:

```
class Details extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {  // Use constructor to initialise `this` properly
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      id: props.location.state.id,
      fname: props.location.state.fname,
      lname: props.location.state.lname,
      email: props.location.state.email,
      ddate: props.location.state.ddate,
      ttime: props.location.state.ttime
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the `routerProps`, that solved my problem of how to pass the variable argument like in URL `/:id` to the component you are routing to while also passing other data in attributes. +1